# Area of triangle formed by points where medians are intersecting the sides

Tags: triangles, area, median

I am looking for a way to find the area of triangle that is formed by points where medians are intersecting the sides in order to solve another question related to medians and triangle.
[image]

What will be the area of triangle DEF if the area of the given triangle is 'A'?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Remember to include your work on the problem. Otherwise it looks like you are asking others to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the position vectors of $B,C$ are $\vec b, \vec c$, then the area of the triangle ABC is $|\vec b \times \vec c|/2$. The position vectors of points F, E, D are  $\vec b/2, \vec c/2, (\vec b+ \vec c)/2$. Area of the small triangle DEF is $|\vec{DE} \times \vec{DF}|=\frac{1}{8}| 
\vec b \times \vec c|$. So the required fraction is $1/4$.

Comment: thanks for such a quick response..so that means the all the four triangles i.e.AEF, DEF,DFB and DEC will be equal. Please correct me if I am wrong. each will be having area which is 1/4 of the original traingle.

Comment: @Ali Yes, your are right.